# Does the Sherman-Morrison formula apply with "rank-one" block matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

Consider the matrix

$$ B = A + \begin{bmatrix} R_{1} & R_{2} \\ R_{1} & R_{2} \end{bmatrix} = A + \begin{bmatrix} I \\ I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} R_{1} & R_{2} \end{bmatrix} $$
where $A$ is an invertible square matrix, and $R_1$ and $R_2$ are symmetric matrices. Notice that the block matrix $R$ is akin to a rank-one matrix, in the sense that the two rows are the same.

If $R_1$ and $R_2$ were scalar, we could use the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to compute $B^{-1}$ in a simple way. Is there a version of that formula that would apply when $R_1$ and $R_2$ are matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). In the link, choose: $U,V^{-1}$ to be eigenvectors corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues of the given matrix

$$UDU^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
R_1 & R_2 \\
R_1 & R_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

$V = U^{-1}$, $C = D$ (in the link). Use only those columns in $U$ with non-zero eigenvalues in $D$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll give this a try, but I suspect that doing the spectral decomposition of $R$ won't be simple in my case.

Comment: You can also use/try $U = [I,I]^T$, $C = I$, $V = [R_1,R_2]$.